# Sql select where clause operation <>

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get column value that has some other value and null but don't want value that equal to some point.

**Example**

```
ID|VID  |IC  |
1 |v001 |123 |
2 |v001 |null|
3 |v003 |456 |
4 |v004 |null|
```

so i want to get ID which IC is not equal to 123. but i only get ID 3 but ID 2 and 4 will not shown out in sql. i have tried `select * from table where IC<>'123' and IC is null` but it shows nothing.

Comment: so you want to see nulls or not?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: yeah i want to see nulls

microsoft sql server 2012

Comment: updated answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `OR`, not `AND`:

```
select * from table where IC != 123 OR IC IS NULL
```

Any comparison with `NULL` produces the [third logic value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), `UNKNOWN`, and any negation of `UNKNOWN` produces `UNKNOWN`, so you have to treat the `NULL`s separately - but, of course, for any particular row, it cannot possibly be true that it's simultaneously got a value different from `123` but at the same time it's `NULL`. So `AND` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks it work !
but i not enough to vote up ur answer am sorry.
thank you anyway

Comment: @UnProgram - you will be able to accept it (tick below the vote buttons) after a suitable time period, to show that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE IC != '123' OR IC IS NULL
```

Comment: but i want to get the null value for iC as well

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table   
WHERE IC != '123'   
OR IC IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select * from table where ISNULL(IC,0)<>'123'
```

Comment: Please add a newline after the `:`. it'll fix the code formatting issue.

Comment: You have to add another newline.

Comment: And add four spaces before the `select` part

Comment: This is tagged Sql-server, not Oracle.